# SonarQube: Coverage incomplete on multimodule gradle project with JaCoCo

Tags: gradle, sonarqube, jacoco

I am building a SonarQube 6.2 server which is already analyzing my Java 8/Gradle 3.3 projects. When adding JaCoCo to a multimodule gradle project, I realized that SonarQube is measuring code coverage on a "per-module" basis:

If a class is located in module `A` and a test for this class is located in module `B`, SonarQube figures the class is *not covered*.

I want to measure code coverage across all modules, not on a per module basis. How do I achieve this?

There are lots of similar questions but no helpful answers, although the situation seems quite common to me. Jenkins for example does that per default.

I decided to build a [blueprint on github](https://github.com/skiedrowski/gradle-jacoco-sonar-blueprint) to clarify the issue.

The main `build.gradle` consists of

```
plugins { id "org.sonarqube" version "2.2.1" }

subprojects {
    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'jacoco'

    repositories { mavenCentral() }
    dependencies { testCompile "junit:junit:4.12" }
}
```

`modA/build.gradle`is empty.

It contains 3 classes: `TestedInModA`, `TestedInModATest` and `TestedViaModB`.

`modB/build.gradle`just declares a dependency to `modA`:

```
dependencies { compile project(':modA') }
```

It contains just one class: `TestedViaModBTest`, testing the class `TestedViaModB` located in `modA`.

My (private) Jenkins instance shows 100% coverage for the two classes included while SonarQube says only the class `TestedInModA` (which is tested in its own module) is covered.

How can I modify my build process to see "cross-module coverage" in SonarQube?

I would love to update my project so future visitors to this question can find a working example.

**My working solution (thanks @Godin)**

1. add the following to the `subprojects` closure

   ```
   tasks.withType(Test) {
       // redirect all coverage data to one file
       // ... needs cleaning the data prior to the build to avoid accumulating coverage data of different runs.
       // see `task cleanJacoco`
       jacoco {
           destinationFile = file("$rootProject.buildDir/jacoco/test.exec")
       }
   }
   ```
2. add

   ```
   task cleanJacoco(dependsOn: 'clean') {  delete "$buildDir/jacoco" }
   ```

*outside* the `subprojects` closure.

Comment: unfortunately the blueprint link is dead.
I am still searching for a working solution.

Comment: sorry @Bobbelinio, it seems I've removed the blueprint from my github account and I did not find another copy. However, the aforementioned solution does not work any more (according to a comment I've found it stopped working when updating to Gradle 5.2.1). Since we've stopped using sonarqube, we did not bother fixing the problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you perform build JaCoCo Gradle Plugin will produce `modA/build/jacoco/test.exec` and `modB/build/jacoco/test.exe` that contain information about execution of tests in `modA` and `modB` respectively. SonarQube performs analysis of modules separately, so during analysis of `modA` for the file `TestedViaModB` it sees only `modA/build/jacoco/test.exec`.

Most common trick to cross boundaries - is to collect all coverage information into single location. This can be done with
JaCoCo Gralde Plugin

- either by changing location - see [`destinationFile`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.testing.jacoco.plugins.JacocoTaskExtension.html) and [`destPath`](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/jacoco_plugin.html) ( since information is appended to `exec` file, don't forget to remove this single location prior to build, otherwise it will be accumulating information from different builds and not just from different modules ),
- either by merging all files into single one - see [`JacocoMerge` task](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.testing.jacoco.tasks.JacocoMerge.html). And then specify this single location to SonarQube as [`sonar.jacoco.reportPath`](https://docs.sonarqube.org/display/PLUG/Code+Coverage+by+Unit+Tests+for+Java+Project).

Another trick: [SonarQube 6.2 with Java Plugin 4.4 supports property `sonar.jacoco.reportPaths`](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARJAVA-1887) allowing to specify multiple locations.

Comment: Thanks @Godin; the `destinationFile` seems to work, but how do I consistently delete the old exec data prior to a new run? Using `jacocoMerge` task seems to have the same result (... besides the original `*.exec` files are kept), but the file is automatically regenerated by the next build. However I was unable to integrate this at the right place (see the commented code in the main `build.gradle` within the github project).

Comment: The `sonar.jacoco.reportPaths` looks promising but seems to be ignored (coverage still 50%, logfile says `Property 'sonar.jacoco.reportPath' is deprecated. Please use 'sonar.jacoco.reportPaths' instead.`) I updated the main `build.gradle` with my attempt.

Comment: @sk_dev about first question from first comment - why not put it into the build directory, so that it will be cleaned on `./gradlew clean build`

Comment: I used `jacoco { destinationFile = file("$rootProject.buildDir/jacoco/test.exec") }` within the `subprojects` closure but it is not cleaned during `./gradlew clean`. Only the subprojects are cleaned... do I need to `apply plugin _____` to the main project? (`apply plugin 'java'` apparently works, but I need to check for side effects...

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in the solution with `sonar.jacoco.reportPaths` (see answer of Godin), have looke at this gradle code:

```
tasks.getByName('sonarqube') {
    doFirst {
        // lazy initialize the property to collect all coverage files
        def jacocoFilesFromSubprojects = subprojects.findAll {it.plugins.hasPlugin('jacoco')}
                .collect {it.tasks.withType(Test)}.flatten().collect {it.jacoco.destinationFile}

        sonarqube.properties {
            property "sonar.jacoco.reportPaths", jacocoFilesFromSubprojects.join(',')
        }
    }
}
```

This will collect all coverage binary files and set them as comma-separated list to the sonar property. Considers all test tasks of sub projects where jacoco is applied and their jacoco destination file configured.