# sonar.jacoco.reportPaths is not working with sonar gradle plugin

Tags: gradle, sonarqube

I have a multi-module gradle project. Tests for one of my module are in separate modules. For ex: ProjectA, ProjectATest1, ProjectATest2, ProjectATest3. Jacoco execution reports are getting created in the test projects. I want to do sonar analysis of my ProjectA and sonar fails to find the jacoco files.

in ProjectA, sonarqube properties, I gave

```
sonarqube{
    properties {
      property "sonar.jacoco.reportPaths","ProjectATest1/gradleBuild/jacoco/Tests.exec", "ProjectATest2/gradleBuild/jacoco/Tests.exec", "ProjectATest3/gradleBuild/jacoco/Tests.exec" 
    }
}
```

But I get this exception

> Could not find method property() for arguments
>   [sonar.jacoco.reportPaths,"ProjectATest1/gradleBuild/jacoco/Tests.exec",
>   "ProjectATest2/gradleBuild/jacoco/Tests.exec",
>   "ProjectATest3/gradleBuild/jacoco/Tests.exec"]

[SonarQube: Coverage incomplete on multimodule gradle project with JaCoCo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41737758/sonarqube-coverage-incomplete-on-multimodule-gradle-project-with-jacoco) the answer says it should work. Is there a bug in sonar gradle plugin?

Comment: I got it fixed by using jacoco merge and merging the files into single file. While it works for me, I wish it worked right out of the box. https://github.com/BolderTechnologies/SonarQube-TotalCoverage

Comment: I just realized that I passed the arguments wrong. All 3 should have been in one argument. Duh.

Answer (score 2):

> Could not find method property() for arguments [sonar.jacoco.reportPaths,"ProjectATest1/gradleBuild/jacoco/Tests.exec", "ProjectATest2/gradleBuild/jacoco/Tests.exec", "ProjectATest3/gradleBuild/jacoco/Tests.exec"]

It means that the method `property` disallow passing 4 arguments. You have to define paths in a one string (comma separated list):

```
sonarqube{
  properties {
    property "sonar.jacoco.reportPaths", "ProjectATest1/gradleBuild/jacoco/Tests.exec,ProjectATest2/gradleBuild/jacoco/Tests.exec,ProjectATest3/gradleBuild/jacoco/Tests.exec" 
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, yes I realized and added it in my comment.