# How can I set-up Maven to create Jacoco coverage for tests for source code another module?

Tags: maven, sonarqube, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin

I have a multi-module Maven project. Many of the tests are in the conventional directory (`src/test/java`) but about 60% are in single module.

By default, Jacoco does not create coverage for those tests.

I'd like the tests in the single module to contribute to coverage.

Nb. We collects coverage in Sonar.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SonarQube: Coverage incomplete on multimodule gradle project with JaCoCo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41737758/sonarqube-coverage-incomplete-on-multimodule-gradle-project-with-jacoco)

Comment: That's a Gradle answer I'm afraid.

Comment: IMO it is generic enough - both questions are mostly about SonarQube.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix this, set the following configuration item:

```
<inclNoLocationClasses>true</inclNoLocationClasses>
```